# Prevents some elements from being edited when using contentEditable

Tags: html

In the sample markup below, when using the html5 `contentEditable="true"`, is there some way that `<span id="cookie">` won't be editable?

```
<div contentEditable="true">
    This text be edited. <span id="nodelete">Except for this text.</span> This can be edited as well.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you set it as an inline `DIV` and set the `contentEditable` to false?

Comment: Holy naked clown Batman! You're right! Why couldn't I have seen that? :)

Comment: I should have put that as an answer!  <slaps forehead>!

Comment: @Westie you should still do that.

Comment: @Paul Can you add your comment as the answer here? I'll note that the `display: inline-block;` is what I added for a span so the editing on both sides still lined-up/worked properly without preventing the editing of the first characters on the left and right. And the contentEditable being equal to `false` prevents the editing of the element itself.

Comment: @bit-less: Done it, but it was a long time ago!  ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, upon the request of bit-less:

The solution I would use is to declare the inner `span` as an inline `div` but set the `contentEditable` to false, like so...

```html
<div contentEditable="true">
    This text can be edited. 
    <div style="display: inline;" contentEditable="false">
        Except for this text.
    </div>
    This can be edited as well.
</div>
```

Comment: That works great! I also styled <span> elements as `display:inline-block;` instead of the default `inline` so the cursor would behavior properly on the left and right of the element. (I'm using pseudos for content from data attributes, so maybe that's why I needed the inline-block).

Comment: Yeah - I see where you're going with that. Got to give data attributes some love - they're a great thing!